# Laravel does not save session after a redirect

Tags: php, laravel, session, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am working with the TwitterOAuth Framework from Abraham to get login via a twitter account to my web app.

I first save the token_secret in the session with the global laravel session helper and then redirect the user to the authorization page on twitter, like this:

```
session(['token_secret' => $requestToken['oauth_token_secret']]);
return Redirect()->away($url);
```

Before the redirect, the token_secret is saved in the session as expected, but when twitter redirects back to my site, its not. I check it like this:

```
dd(session()->all());
```

It worked with the PHP Session Handling but I decided to use the laravel session helper instead.
My Routes are like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::prefix('/twitter')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/authenticate', [TwitterController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('twitter_authenticate');
        Route::get('/saveCredentials', [TwitterController::class, 'saveCredentials'])->name('twitter_saveCredentials');
    });
});
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem today and could solve it with the use of the `cookie` session driver.

Before the response is send to the browser the cookie needs to be filled with the data.

For other drivers the response is send first and the session data will be saved afterwards via the terminate function.

Answer (score -1):

you can use redirect and with and automatically laravel send data to another route.

```
return redirect('/dashboard')->with('token_secret', $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'])
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I already tried it, its not working either.

For me, it feels like I need to reassign the session to the user, the file for the session still exists in my project with the expected token.

Is there a way to give the user his session back after a redirect?